# List names along with id

Tags: sql

So I have 2 tables:ActsIn and Stars.
I want to list the given names and family names of actors which have appeared in 4 or more movies and the number of movies they appeared in.[image]

with my current code I am only able to display the id of the actors, how can I also display their givenname and familyname?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    a.Starid, s.givenname, s.familyname, count(*)
from Actsin as a
    inner join Stars as s on s.Starid = a.Starid
group by a.Starid, s.givenname, s.familyname
having count(*) >= 4
```